# How to use point instead of comma th:field in Thymealeaf Html Part?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a problem with using point instead of a comma in the Thymleaf HTML part.

Here is my code snippet.

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{productCost}" required class="form-control" />
```

It is a value coming from the database. I got **125,00** but I really want to get **125.00**.

I have to use `th:field`. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using Spring here? If so, you should tag your question as such, since that may affect how this question can best be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? Not used thymeleaf but assuming it is similar to Twig..

```
/* 
* Set minimum integer digits and thousands separator: 
* 'POINT', 'COMMA', 'WHITESPACE', 'NONE' or 'DEFAULT' (by locale).
* Also works with arrays, lists or sets
*/
${#numbers.formatInteger(num,3,'POINT')}
${#numbers.arrayFormatInteger(numArray,3,'POINT')}
${#numbers.listFormatInteger(numList,3,'POINT')}
${#numbers.setFormatInteger(numSet,3,'POINT')}
```

ref: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers

So:

```
<input type="text" th:field="${#numbers.formatInteger(productCost,3,'POINT')}" required class="form-control" />
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Like i say, i'm going off the docs and not realtime testing it, what does it display? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '#numbers' available as request attribute

Comment: Maybe: ${#numbers.formatDecimal(productCost,3,2,'POINT')} ?

Comment: It didn't work again.